# Android app is not responding to the back button

Tags: android, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have a ScheduledExecutorService that runs a method every 20ms.

```
beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 0, 20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In addition, the BluetoothService gets continuous data. I want to stop all data gathering and scheduled methods when I press the back button. But, even when I press the button the app doesn't actually exit but keeps running in the foreground - basically the UI of the app stops responding. Since I am using the ScheduledExecutorService which creates a new thread this should not be happening. And, a while after pressing the back button repeatedly or pressing the home button, when the app finally goes off screen, the data gathering and scheduled methods don't stop even then. I have tried cancelling and stopping these in my onDestroyView(), onDestroy() and even in onPause() methods.

```
public void onDestroy() 
{ 
  if (beeperHandle != null)
        beeperHandle.cancel(true);
  if(scheduler.isShutdown())
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
  mBluetoothLeService = null;   
  mBLEConnectionHandler = null;
  mBLEReceiverHandler = null;       
}
```

How do I ensure that the UI doesn't freeze and the app stops everything on the back button?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
    finish();
}
```

Comment: It says  the method onBackPressed() of BFragment must override or implement a supertype method. My class extends Fragment.